# How to add user id in Excel header / footer?

Tags: excel, header, footer

Does anyone know how to add user id to the Excel header or footer? I know I can set it in a macro but I'm trying to avoid it. Is there any shortcut like &D or &t for user id?

Answer (score 0):

there is no formula (in the header dialogue, or in Excel in general) that pulls the username. You would have to do VBA.

Answer (score 0):

The *user* or *author* is not a prebuilt field that can be inserted into a header/footer like `&[Page]` for page number. The available header/footer elements are shown in the **Header & Footer Tools, Design** context menu (available once you are in View, Page Layout)

[image: Header/Footer Elements]

However, there are some prebuilt commands that will insert the current user as text (not an updateable field). Click the large **Header** menu button at the far left of the above image and insert *<user> Page <page no> <date>* or *Prepared by <user> <date> Page <page no>*. The same prepared phrases are available for the Footer.

These are accessed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>,<kbd>H</kbd>,<kbd>H</kbd>. They can also be assigned to the [QAT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-the-Quick-Access-Toolbar-6c616455-653c-451c-93f7-96082e98de4d) or menu hotkey(s).